# Is as.logical buggy?

Tags: r

Does anybody know why `as.logical` function does not correctly handle `NULL` entries ?

```
as.logical(NULL)
#logical(0)

as.logical(list(NA, 1, logical(0)))
#[1]   NA TRUE   NA

as.logical(list(NA, 1, logical(0), NULL))
#Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

Actual results is an error while *(logically)* expected result should be a vector [NA, TRUE, NA, NA]

Comment: Use `lapply` or `sapply` to work with lists eg `lapply(list(NA, 1, logical(0), NULL),as.logical)` Also why do you expect it to be `NA`?

Comment: I just expect to get the same result as for as.logical(logical(0)) in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer the reason for the error:
`NULL` has two(or more) uses, the focus in this case is on a pairlist. From the docs:

> NULL is also used as the empty pairlist: see the examples. Because pairlists are often promoted to lists, you may encounter NULL being promoted to an empty list.

Therefore, the error is due to `NULL` being interpreted as a pairlist.

To reproduce the error:

```
as.logical(list(as.pairlist(NULL)))
```

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

The trouble then is figuring out when `NULL` is promoted to an empty list. See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/list) for details on lists.

> An empty pairlist, pairlist() is the same as NULL. This is different from list(): some but not all operations will promote an empty pairlist to an empty list.

Comment: @neoniraArinoem, welcome to SO! If found this answer useful/helpful and sufficient for you, you can 1. up-vote the answer, 2. (and even better) accept this answer using the V next to it. That way, the user will get the point for helping you and other users will now this question is solved and will add only important/alternative answers.